# Starting IPython

Tags: ipython

I want to run IPython (version 0.12) on my Windows XP computer on which I already have Python 2.7 installed.

I installed via the Windows binary installer, but after installation IPython did not show up in the menu and could not be started with the command window, though a IPython folder was created in the C: path.

I also tried the other download option (tar.gz and zip), but again failed.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7):

distribute/setuptools is needed to create the start menu entries. Download and run [this script](http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py) to install distribute, then try the installation with the executable installer again.

It may not be on your path, but there should also be an `ipython.exe` somewhere. I think it's somewhere like `C:\Python2.7\Scripts\`.