# python argument parsing issue only on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

When I try a [script](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~hannes/importer.py) to import CSVs into MonetDB databases as [suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65174/38399) by its author, it runs fine on my mac (Python 2.7.6 from the Anaconda distro) but it raises an `error: too few arguments` on Windows 2012 Server (Python 2.7.5 from Anaconda).

I think all flags but `--database` should be optional, plus you need to specify a filename — this is exactly working on my mac, not on Windows.

What is the way to bugfix this? Is this a known issue with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for Windows?

Or if I should escape `\` characters in the filename, why doesn't Python complain about the file not existing, why about too few arguments? (And in any case, as I specify the files in a Windows batch file, I cannot escape `\` there easily.)

I repeat the argument parsing part of the script for convenience:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A "smarter" CSV loader for MonetDB, v.0.3, hannes@cwi.nl, 2014-05')
parser.add_argument('--database', help='Database name to connect to', default='')
parser.add_argument('--port', help='MonetDB TCP port, defaults to 50000', default='50000')
parser.add_argument('--user', help='MonetDB username, defaults to "monetdb"', default='monetdb')
parser.add_argument('--password', help='MonetDB password, defaults to "monetdb"', default='monetdb')
parser.add_argument('--header',action='store_true', help='set if given CSV file has a header in the first line')
parser.add_argument('--yes',action='store_true', help='if set, assume Yes on all questions')
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='+', help='One or many CSV files to be imported')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows installation is incomplete for Python, having it in the PATH is not enough. The problem is resolved if one types out `python importer.py` properly, and not only `importer.py`, on the command line. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12421946/938408

Strange that a parsing problem was the red flag, but that's what it is.

Comment: As suggested in that other SO thread, I'd print `sys.argv` to see what `argparse` has to work with.  By default it parses `sys.argv[1:]`.  If that is empty, `argparse` would give your error, since it can't find a value to use for `files`.